# asp.net mvc 3 json values not recieving at controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

the problem is that i am not able to recieve any value in the controller . what could be wrong? the code is here.

```
  $('#save').click(function () {

        var UserLoginViewModel = { UserName: $('vcr_UserName').val(),
            Password: $('vcr_Password').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "/User/Login",
            data: JSON.stringify(UserLoginViewModel),
            contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (mydata) {
                $("#message").html("Login");
            },
            error: function () {
                $("#message").html("error");
            },
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json"
        });
        return false;
    });
});

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(UserLoginViewModel UserLoginViewModel)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need an action filter or similar to intercept the json from the post body.

Here's a starter

[Provider Factory](http://yobriefcase.posterous.com/aspnet-mvc3s-jsonvalueproviderfactory)

but here is the article that sorted this for me [On Haacked](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx)

It is good if you know the type you are deserialising into up front, but if you need polymorphism you'll end up using these ideas in an action filter.

Comment: MVC 3 includes built in support for JSON model binding

Answer (score 3):

As you're using MVC3 - you should be able to take advantage of the built in JSON model binding.

Your code example has a couple of typos: `contentType` and `dataType` are lowercase...(they should have an uppercase "T")

[jQuery ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

After you POST up the correct contentType/dataType, MVC should automatically bind your object to the posted JSON.

Comment: Thanks! I had the same problem with misspelt options aswell